# Index was out of range in grid row command

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to reach gridView a cell's value.But it gives the error is 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. grid row command'

Can somebody help me?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  GridLines="None"
            PageSize="5" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="Grd_Allergys_PageIndexChanging"
            OnRowCommand="grdList_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="grdList_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="grdList_RowEditing">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LangId" HeaderText="LangId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LangName" HeaderText="LangName" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("LangId") %>'
                            ImageUrl="~/Image/edit.jpg" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("LangId")%>'
                            ImageUrl="~/Image/delete_icon.gif" OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to continue ?')" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <PagerSettings Mode="Numeric" />
        </asp:GridView>

 protected void grdList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
        DBDataContext dc = new DBDataContext();

        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {                       
           int rowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
           string LangName = grdList.DataKeys[rowIndex]["LangName"].ToString();                              
        }                    
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning `LangId` and assuming it as row `index` in command argument. If id is greater then number of rows then you should get out of range `index`

*Change*

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("LangId")%>'
```

*To*

```
CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You also haven't set `DataKeys`  up.

Add `DataKeys="LangName"` to your GridView definition.

Answer (score 0):

commandargument=`<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and this is the solution I found.

In the **RowCommand** the first line must be :

```
if (e.CommandName == "Page") return;
```